# How to replace values of multiple columns in data.table object?

Tags: r, data.table

As of now my data.table code works, but based on my reading on here and in the data.table vignette I think this can be done even faster OR more efficiently...

Here's the code:

```
setkey(dat.tab, DesNode)
for (j in 1:(dim(tmp.probs)[2])){
    dat.tab[data.table(c(generations)), paste("compD", j, sep="_") := tmp.probs[,j]]
}
```

Basically, I have a data.table object, dat.tab, where I want to replace column values (in this case, there are 32 columns, but I am indexing them by their name) based on the row order of a vector of row numbers called "generations". Is this the most efficient way of doing this in data.table? This particular snippet of code gets used a lot, and when I profile a non-trivial amount of the system time is being used up by various functions for performing this (naive and possibly dumb) loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can probably do:

```
newcols <- names(tmp.probs[, -"generations"])
dat.tab[generations, (newcols) := tmp.probs[, -"generations"]]
```

output:

```
   DesNode V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30 V31 V32
1:       A  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2:       B  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
3:       C  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
4:       D  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
5:       E  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
```

data:

```
dat.tab <- data.table(DesNode=LETTERS[1:5])
generations <- c(2, 4, 1, 3, 5)
(tmp.probs <- data.table(generations=generations, 
    as.data.table(matrix(rep(generations, 32), nrow=5))))

#   generations V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30 V31 V32
#1:           2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
#2:           4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
#3:           1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
#4:           3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
#5:           5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
```